# Swift-y way to parse integer prefixed strings like NSString

Tags: swift, parsing

Consider the following:

```
Int("30 minutes") // nil
("30 minutes" as NSString).integerValue // 30
```

What is a more Swift-y way to get `30` from `30 minutes`?

Bearing in mind it may be `30mins` or `30\tminudos` or `30 मिनट`.

`NSString` method was convenient because it behaved similar to JavaScript `parse` until the first non-integer char.

**Update** Note: just like in JS `parseInt` function, if my string has more digits beyond string chars, e.g. `30mins3`, then the cast to `NSString` returns just the first chars, e.g.:

```
("30mins3" as NSString).integerValue // 30
```

Comment: Compare [Extract Float from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45206001/1187415) – essentially the same question,  only about extracting a floating point number.

Comment: @MartinR interesting. the cleanest there seems to be the `Scanner()` approach; but that derives from `NSObject` so it's about as Swifty as `as NSString` cast :/ the rest is based on parsing strings which i was really hoping to avoid.

Comment: Can there be leading spaces? Or a leading + or - sign? – Scanner handles all that, and is available even on Linux. Otherwise you have to do your own parsing. Have a look at https://www.objc.io/blog/2019/02/05/a-scanner-alternative/ for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the following function that finds the first non-number and then makes a substring of the part up to that character and converts it to an int

```
extension String {
    func integerValue() -> Int? {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(where: {!$0.isNumber && $0.isASCII}) {
            return Int(self.prefix(upTo: index))
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

or alternatively use `prefix(while:)`

```
extension String {
    func integerValue() -> Int? {
        return Int(self.prefix(while: {$0.isNumber && $0.isASCII})) 
    }
}
```

Example

```
let strings = ["30 minutes", "30min3", "gfd"]
for str in strings {
    if let number = str.integerValue() {
        print(number)
    }
}
```

outputs

> 30
>   30

Comment: Note that `isNumber` is also true for "⅚", "㊈", or "๒".

Comment: @MartinR Strangely enough my code works fine when I try it on an online playground with those characters, I need to try it again at home. But I guess one could add `&& $0.isASCII` to the condition

Comment: I admit that this might be a bit far fetched, but your original version would not parse 123 in "123⅚".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to get all the Int from your string.

```
var str = "30mins"
let result = str.filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0)}
print(result)
```

Comment: This does not work on the sample i provided for `30mins`. it is simply calling `Int("30")` and i pointed out in my question that is not working for what i am trying to achieve :)

Comment: My answer for general problem, in your case you can map your problem using my code, if you just want to get 30 then on array array.first you will get 30, might be you have something different string later more int values thats why i put that answer.

Comment: Mate, your answer does not work for the question asked. i don't know what `general problem` are you talking about, but it sure isn't one of mine ;)

Comment: try your code with `var str = "30mins"`. It returns empty array

Comment: I like this one, didn't know that range will work on string chars like that. The only problem is, if i do `var str = "30mins3"` i get `"303"`, whereas the `("30mins3" as NSString).integerValue` does return `30` as does Javascript.

Comment: Hi @zaitsman in this case you need to be sure what kind of input you are getting, if not sure then it could be multiple test case occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of Swift `Regex` and `Regexbuilder` at WWDC 2022 smart solutions are

```
import RegexBuilder

let string = "30 minutes"

let pattern = Regex {
    Capture { OneOrMore(.digit)
    } transform: { Int($0) }
}
if let matchCapture = string.firstMatch(of: pattern) {
    let integerValue = matchCapture.output.0
    print(integerValue)
}
```

or

```
let string = "30 minutes"
let integerValue = Int(string.firstMatch(of: /\d+/)?.output ?? "0")!
print(integerValue)
```